# Derived (commutator) groups of isomorphic groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My algebra is a bit rusty, but lately I've started learning algebraic-topology so I need to refresh my memory.

Assume G,H are isomorphic groups. Are G' and H' isomorphic as well?

As far as I can remember It should be, since G and H are practicly the same group.

thanks

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: Aside from element names, $G$ and $H$ will be identical - any group theoretic property that holds for $G$, will hold for $H$. If $G$ has any special subgroups, $H$ will as well, and the isomorphism will preserve their properties too; isomorphisms restrict to isomorphisms.